# How do you remove the command part from a discord message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot for discord and I need to use the text after the command for something. I'm not able to get it to work.

I have tried to use `.replace` and `.removeprefix` but it says that message:

```py
object has no attribute .replace/removeprefix
```

```py
if message.content.startswith("/add "):
    message1 = message
    message1 = message1.removeprefix('/add ')
```

That is the code that is currently giving me the error

Comment: Post the error message so we have more of an idea of what is happening

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the message content is defined as `message.content`, but you're trying to call the `removeprefix` method on `message` (which is an object containing the actual message content within). Because `message` is an object and not a string, it doesn't have the relevant method. It should work if you try:

```
if message.content.startswith("/add "):
    message1 = message.content
    message1 = message1.removeprefix('/add ')
```

Also, make sure you're using python3 as the `removeprefix` method was introduced in Python 3.9!